# Flash/AIR: Possible to restrict printing to physical printers - not virtual/pdf

Tags: flash, air

Is it possible to restrict printing from FlashPlayer/AIR to physical printer devices - preventing print to virtual devices like pdf or image drivers?

Comment: Nope. See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is NO, not possible. 
(Thank you for enlighting me, David!)

Jonas

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.